# What is the first animal you need to summon in world 1-9 of Scribblenauts Remix?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

In World 1-9 of Scribblenauts Remix, you are presented with an extremely abbreviated evolutionary tree with two missing entries.  I cannot figure out what type of animal the game thinks would come between a lizard and a mammoth.

I've tried dog, cat, sabretooth tiger, bird, even giant metal chicken, but nothing works.  What type of animal is the game looking for?

Comment: I don't have remix, and I don't remember this level from the DS, but did you consider a dinosaur?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I summoned a Dinosaur, and that worked.

Comment: Of course, the answer is obvious now...

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out too, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a dragon.  I have no idea why, I guess it's large like a mammoth and scaly like a lizard?

Comment: Or close enough to a dinosaur that the game allows it.

Comment: Of course it's dragon. What else would it be? It's as big as a mammoth and scaley like a lizard.